# Usage of a namespace member from a different file

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

In my project, I have an existing file:

### ABC_Existing.h

```
    namespace Cpld_A
    {
       const int XXX;
    }
```

And ABC_Existing.cc uses the variable XXX doing 'using namespace Cpld'.

I created a new file:

### XYZ_New.h

```
    namespace Cpld_B
    {
       const int XXX;
    }
```

And I am trying to use it in XYZ_New.cc. When I compile, I get error saying ambiguous declaration of variable XXX between Cpld_A and Cpld_B.
There is no relation between ABC_Existing and XYZ_New. And ABC_Existing.h is not included (directly or indirectly) in XYZ_New.h/cc. But, all these files are in the same folder and build together.

How can this problem happen, and how do I resolve this ?
Appreciate your help !!!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the ambiguity is because both the same namespaces and hence the symbol names within are imported in to your current namespace by some indirect obscure way.

A simple way to resolve the ambiguity is by using the fully qualified names of the symbols, when referring to them:

```
Cpld_A::XXX     
Cpld_B::XXX
```

Comment: Is there a way I can find how this is getting linked ?